# Python is telling me an indention is expected where I put one

Tags: python, block, indentation

OK, here's a piece of the script:

```
def start():  
    print "While exploring the ruins of a recently abandoned castle you stumble apon the entrance to what appears to be a dungeon. You are carrying on you a...
```

I keep getting the error

```
user@ubuntu:~/Documents/python$ python dungeon.py  
  File "dungeon.py", line 533  
    def start():  
    ^  
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

I know this is probably obvious but does anyone have any clue as to what I'm doing wrong hear? I tried replacing the indent
with spaces only and tabs only but it still gives me this error. I appreciate any answers.

Comment: what's on the line(s) before `def start():`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it expects `def start():` to be indented. What does the code look like before that?

Comment: That was it, the line before it was indented. Thank you guys for the help.

Answer (score 6):

- Make sure you aren't mixing tabs and spaces for indentation
- Your string is missing a closing quote

Further, is `def start()` actually indented in your file? It isn't indented in this question, and that's what Python seems to be complaining about.

Answer (score 2):

Check that whitespace is consistent (i.e. mixing tabs and spaces?).

If your editor supports, I suggest to make it expand all tabs to (4) spaces. This avoids such confusion, also when copy-pasting code.

In vim:

```
:se tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 expandtab
:%retab
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure there is a `tab` character in that position? Try open it with `vi` and add yourself the `tab` just to check is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try looking at the code just before that line. Is there an unfinished block (line ending with `:`)? If yes, put something in that block – a `pass` statement will do.